# How to pass a function from a class to another class in Swift while initialization?

Tags: swift

My aim is to split up logic into several classes.

Therefore data should be fetched in classA. As soon as it is available the data is to be passes to class B for further calculation.

My approach was to create an instance of classA within classB.

In order for classA to be able to pass the newest values to classB, I want to initialize it passing a setter function.

Here is my example code:

```
class ClassA {
let closure: (Int) -> Void

init(closure: @escaping (Int) -> Void) {
    self.closure = closure
}

func fetchData() {
//fetch data
let exampleData = 1234
closure(exampleData)
    }
}

class ClassB {
let classAInstance: ClassA
var data: Int

init() {
    classAInstance = ClassA(closure: classBMethod)
    data = 0
}

func classBMethod(value: Int) {
    print("Value is \(value)")
    data = value
    } 
}

let classB = ClassB()
classB.classAInstance.fetchData() // to be automatically called from classA in a certain interval
```

Everything I have tried always led to "'self' used before all stored properties are initialized".

I found code examples that use the "weak" keyword but I was not able to figure out how to use it in this case.

What should I do to implement the desired behaviour?

Comment: Instead of passing the closure through the initialiser, how about doing `var closure: ((Int) -> Void)?` and assign the closure to `closure` after `classAInstance = ClassA()`?

Answer (score 0):

There could be different ways but you can try this for simple requirements.

```swift
class ClassA {
    let closure: (Int) -> Void
    
    init(closure: @escaping (Int) -> Void) {
        self.closure = closure
    }
    
    func fetchData() {
        //fetch data
        let exampleData = 1234
        closure(exampleData)
    }
}

class ClassB {
    private var classAInstance: ClassA?
    var data: Int = 0
    
    private func observeDataChanges() {
        classAInstance = ClassA(closure: classBMethod)
    }
    
    func classBMethod(value: Int) {
        print("Value is \(value)")
        data = value
    }
    
    func fetchData() {
        if classAInstance == nil {
            observeDataChanges()
        }
        classAInstance?.fetchData()
    }
}

let classB = ClassB()
classB.fetchData()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Delegate pattern to achieve your goal:

```swift
protocol ClassADelegate: AnyObject {
    func onFetchData(_ value: Int)
}


final class ClassA {
    weak var delegate: ClassADelegate?
    
    func fetchData(_ completion: @escaping (Int) -> Void) {
        //fetch data
        let exampleData = 1234
        delegate?.onFetchData(exampleData)
    }
}

final class ClassB {
    let classAInstance: ClassA
    var data: Int

    init(
        classAInstance: ClassA = ClassA(),
        data: Int = 0
    ) {
        self.classAInstance = classAInstance
        self.data = data
        classAInstance.delegate = self
    }

    func classBMethod(value: Int) {
        print("Value is \(value)")
        data = value
    }
}

extension ClassB: ClassADelegate {
    func onFetchData(_ value: Int) {
        classBMethod(value: value)
    }
}
```